# Multiple options for a product in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a product t-shirt and on its page there will be different styles of the t-shirt listed like for women, men, children. Selecting any one style, changes the current product to the selected one and updates the price and all stuffs in the page.

So when a user buys the product we should be able to identify that he bought the t-shirt for a particular category.

[Reference site](http://www.zazzle.com/santa_dont_stop_believin_tee_shirts-235750122194134952)

Click on See all styles on right bar brings up a popup showing all options available for the pdt. Selecting any one option updates the page.

Does `magento` has any inbuilt options for this or is there any module available for this ?
Any helps?

Comment: Yeah magento has built in such functionality.You can easily do that by creating multiple categories for each men,women etc.And than add products to each category.

Comment: @Mahmood Rehman : but how can relate these pdts to the main pdt ? Will making this as a related pdt do any good ?

Comment: There are multiple options for products like group,related,configurable in magento.Depends upon your requirements.Did you work in magento before ??

Comment: Yeah i have. Were you able to identify the functionality from the reference site i had given ?

Comment: Look at the menus.Clothing and T shirts,These are the categories.

Comment: I have done the functionality.Created a configurable product with attributes and added simple pdts as associated products to it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a configurable product with multiple options.

A tutorial on how to do this is here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTmjwbVXDM0

Comment: [Answers should contain more than just a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).
Please include all essential information in the answer, and provide links for reference only.